# Is there any way that I can get a friend's online status with Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api

Can I get friend's online status without using FQL?

I am using Rails3 and accessing Facebook's Graph API using the Koala gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I cant access the online status using graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you need to get the 'friends_online_presence' permission from the user.  See the facebook OAuth permissions list [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

EDIT: I've looked further into this, and can't seem to get the online_presence field even when this permission has been properly set.  It doesn't seem to appear as a possible field in the Facebook Graph API anywhere.  Strange.